# hevc number of coding tree blocks per slice

Tags: parsing, slice, hevc, h.265

I trying to determine the number of coding tree blocks contained in each slice of a hevc picture without actually doing any decoding - aside from sps pps and slice header parsing.

Can the end slice address be calculated from the slice header?

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a few changes to the encoder so it gives you the partitioning information in a log file. 
Can that be an option for you?

Comment: Thankds. I want to accomplish this without any supplementary files.

Comment: Then I don't see any way other than a little decoding the essential syntax elements. To be honest, I don't really understand what you CAN do and what you DON'T WANT TO do. Technically, it is impossible to have the partitioning information without decoding split flags, which requires modeling proper CABAC contexts, which also requires a bit of decoding. Tell us more about your goal and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know neither parameters sets nor the slices headers contains this information, I can assure you that because I am working on HM codec in the decoder side.

a simple way to find nub of CTU in the current frame is to add simply this line in the `TDecGop::filterPicture` (inside TLibDecoder/TDecGop.cpp) :

`std::cout << "*Slice Cur End Ctu Ts Addr :\t" << pcSlice->getSliceCurEndCtuTsAddr() << "\n";` after recovering the slice pointer.

or better :

```
std::cout << "numCtusInFrame :\t" << pcPic->getNumberOfCtusInFrame()  << "\n";
```

in 1st line of the function. you will get in the log screen (file) :

```
*Slice Cur End Ctu Ts Addr :    30
POC    0 TId: 0 ( I-SLICE, QP 21 ) [DT  0.087] [L0 ] [L1 ] [:,(unk)]
```

or

```
numCtusInFrame :        30
POC    0 TId: 0 ( I-SLICE, QP 21 ) [DT  0.087] [L0 ] [L1 ] [:,(unk)]
```